# backBarButtonItem in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

```
var backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CUSTOM", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: nil)
    newNavigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Where is `newNavigationItem: UINavigationItem`

I want custom back title. It shows "Back" text or "Title of last view". So it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method that Yogesh Suthar said will replace the whole back button, so you will not have the default left arrow sign! I suggest to use this code:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Do you put this in the parent view controller?

Comment: Yeah. You can do this anywhere that you have access to the navigationViewcontroller.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting the leftBarButtonItem is a workaround. In swift 2 I used this in the viewDidLoad of the view controller pushing to the one I wanted to change the back title on: `navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)`

Comment: @Majid +1 for best answer. Now I can also use this solution. :)

Comment: this answer is obsolete

Answer (score 5):

Use `leftBarButtomItem`

```
newNavigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

should be

```
newNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats work. For what backBarButtonIteam right now? Also one question: what need to put in "Action" that this button work like usually Back button

Comment: Ah. There also no arrow left more. How to add it?

Comment: @MaximDroy Why aren't you setting the title property instead? No need to create a whole new UIBarButtonItem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282760/back-text-displayed-in-ios7-navigationbar-when-view-title-is-long

Comment: @MaximDroy Sorry for late reply. For your first question about "Action", you need to create a custom function and you need to pop VC, you can use this code `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`.

Comment: Setting leftBarButtonItem is a workaround - instead set the backBarButtonItem to a custom UIBarButtonItem in the viewDidLoad of the view controller pushing to the one you want to change as suggested by  @Majid below http://stackoverflow.com/a/30250603/169902

Comment: Using this solution will disable swipe back action.

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
  let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",
         style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

}

```
func backAction() -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting custom UIBarButtonItem as backBarButtonItem in my case had some padding from left. After close inspection it showed default image from Back Button was visible.

What worked for me:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

With this logic swipe back is working normally and also click on back button pops viewcontroller.