# Size text to fit on navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a UIViewController with title "La Bolsa al minuto". When I push to another VC, I can see the back button with text "< Back". This is the code:

```
self.title = @"La Bolsa al minuto";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

If I shorten the title (one letter is enough), the back button item displays "< La Bolsa al minut".

```
self.title = @"La Bolsa al minut";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Is there any way to reduce that title size to let me display the full title?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535507/change-font-of-back-navigation-bar-button

Comment: I knew that answer. I'm asking not to change to any font or size in particular, but to fit the text.

Comment: Then try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282760/back-text-displayed-in-ios7-uinavigationbar-when-view-title-is-long

or give more info

Comment: Post answer, any feedback?

Comment: @OMGHaveFun you didn't really answer my question. It's not about creating a custom button but it's about to fit title size on it.

Answer (score 0):

In UIViewController with title "La Bolsa al minuto".

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

//Title for 1 VC
    self.title = @"La Bolsa al minuto";

//Title for back button
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"La Bolsa..."
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil];
}
```