# Display "..." when backBarButtonItem have long text

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

i'm a newbie with iOS programming. I work with app use **Navigation Bar**, and set text for **Back** button like this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"my text" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

it work fine. But, the problem occur when my text is long, **backBarButtonItem** display with default text is **Back**.

So, the question is : How can i display long text in **backBarButtonItem**, maybe display "..." instead of full text. Or Can i use custom view replace with default Navigation Bar?

P/s : i have refer ["back" text displayed in iOS7 UINavigationBar when view title is long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282760/back-text-displayed-in-ios7-uinavigationbar-when-view-title-is-long) but it not helpful for me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["back" text displayed in iOS7 UINavigationBar when view title is long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282760/back-text-displayed-in-ios7-uinavigationbar-when-view-title-is-long)

Comment: @GuyDaher , sorry but it not helpful and no answer accepted to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
UIButton *btnLeft=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnLeft.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, button.widh, button.height);
[btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBackBarItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnLeft setTitle:@"YOUR TEXT"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnLeft.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font_name" size:25.0];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnLeft];
```

May this help you

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it not help for me, it just show **leftBarButtonItem** , NOT **backBarButtonItem** in this case

Comment: Can you try this ?
Select Navigaiton Item - > Show the attributes inspector - > Give the Title you want

Answer (score 1):

use `sizeToFit` to show full text in `UIButton`

```
    UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20) ];
    [btnBack setTitle:@"Skip" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnBack.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Medium" size:15];
    [btnBack sizeToFit];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backActionEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSkip];
```

Comment: probably you cannot display long text to backBarButtonItem, so you need to set leftBarButtonItem and perform     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   on backActionEvent (i.e. UIControlEventTouchUpInside).

Comment: Yup, but how can i show "<" arrow if i set **leftBarButtonItem**

Comment: if you want to show arrow than you need to set arrow image in UIButton object (before text).

Comment: I'll try, but have small question, how can i limit length of button title, because i have use **rightBarButtonItem**

Comment: refer this for image + text in UIButton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios and back arrow image (change image colour as per your convenient) https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-back-128.png

Comment: you cannot limit it by char count but you can limit it by its width size , so set width size as per your text char count and don't use sizeToFit property

Comment: Sure, i think this is the best solution for now. I'll make accepted for your answer. Thanks bro